# Microsoft Data Access Application Block Date type precision

Tags: vb.net, oracle, enterprise-library

We are working on an ASP.Net/VB.Net application using Enterprise Library for our data access (DAAB).

We are trying to store DateTime values in an Oracle Date field. However, the precision is being lost. Currently only the year, month, and date are being stored. We need better precision than this.

Oracle Dates are supposed to "includes not just the month, day, and year, but also 
the hour, minute, and second. "

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the base domain object having a type of System.Date which was causing a loss in precision. In future, I will have to check the type of the data all the way from the top to bottom.